# recursive query with select * raises ORA-01789

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

This is a minimized version of complex recursive query. The query works when columns in *recursive member* (second part of `union all`) of recursive CTE are listed explicitly:

```sql
with t (c,p) as (
  select 2,1 from dual
), rec (c,p) as (
  select c,p from t
  union all
  select t.c,t.p from rec join t on rec.c = t.p
)
select * from rec
```

I don't get why error `ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns` is raised when specified `t.*` instead.

```sql
with t (c,p) as (
  select 2,1 from dual
), rec (c,p) as (
  select c,p from t
  union all
  select t.* from rec join t on rec.c = t.p
)
select * from rec
```

Why `t.*` is not equivalent to `t.c,t.p` here? Could you please point me to documentation for any reasoning?

UPDATE: reproducible on 11g and 18 ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e547cde1c5e5bd1f23d4276a2cede1a)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally [asked on AskTom forum](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:105770187902641::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9543970700346889184) and according to response from Oracle expert Connor McDonald, this behavior is in compliance with documentation, namely the sentence *The number of column aliases following WITH query_name and the number of columns in the SELECT lists of the anchor and recursive query blocks must be the same* which can be found [in this paragraph](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#d436015e2085).

The point is, the expansion of star expression is done after checking whether the numbers of columns are same. Hence one must list columns explicitly, shortening to star is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there could be some kind of bug to me. I modified the query slightly just to test various cases and am now able to reproduce an `ORA-00600` error in my Oracle 19.6.0.0.0 database! Running the problematic query on apex.oracle.com or on livesql.oracle.com (which is running 19.8.0.0.0) also results in errors. Reporting it to Oracle now!

Comment: Thanks. I attached version and fiddle which forgot to do yesterday. Good to know even 19 suffers with this problem. Could you provide some bug ID or public URL to trace Oracle response and link it from here?

Comment: The bug has not been officially filed yet, it is still an SR. Also, the query I submitted that is returning the ORA-00600 is a slightly modified version of your query.

Comment: I got official Oracle answer, see my self-answer if you are interested. (I also removed `ORA-00600` tag since it is not clear on what modification of query it is raised.)